# Thumbnail for every fields in an embed with discord.py? Is it possible?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

I'm searching to do a bot that plays with the users and I have to create an "embed-shop" where people can consult the things that they would to buy. Every item should be a field and I'd like to add also an image (without using discord nitro) for every item, but is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer: No, it's not possible

Comment: Yeah ,as I though....

Comment: You could use emojis in your field names, although they won't render particularly large.